# git revert in Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is it possible to do "git revert"s in Egit to rollback changes by creating a new commit (as opposed to checking out an older commit or doing a hard reset which doesn't create a new commit rolling back the changes)?

This seems like an important feature if you have a central repository in case you ever need to undo changes that has already been pushed there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider this [commit from 5 days ago](http://egit.eclipse.org/w/?p=jgit.git;a=commit;h=117d081f44f8c9f99f60c27cedf5298199b8e8f6), called ' **Merge "Implement a revert command"** ' (Shawn Pearce), it seems it will be available soon.

The [diff are here](http://egit.eclipse.org/w/?p=jgit.git;a=commitdiff;h=117d081f44f8c9f99f60c27cedf5298199b8e8f6;hp=ff7149fb95d11e26e3409903a19cfde7df3ff90e):

```
public class RevertCommandTest extends RepositoryTestCase {
       @Test
       public void testRevert() throws IOException, JGitInternalException,
                       GitAPIException {
               Git git = new Git(db);

               writeTrashFile("a", "first line\nsec. line\nthird line\n");
               git.add().addFilepattern("a").call();
               git.commit().setMessage("create a").call();

               writeTrashFile("b", "content\n");
               git.add().addFilepattern("b").call();
               git.commit().setMessage("create b").call();

               writeTrashFile("a", "first line\nsec. line\nthird line\nfourth line\n");
               git.add().addFilepattern("a").call();
               git.commit().setMessage("enlarged a").call();
               writeTrashFile("a",
                               "first line\nsecond line\nthird line\nfourth line\n");
               git.add().addFilepattern("a").call();
               RevCommit fixingA = git.commit().setMessage("fixed a").call();

               writeTrashFile("b", "first line\n");
               git.add().addFilepattern("b").call();
               git.commit().setMessage("fixed b").call();

               git.revert().include(fixingA).call();

               assertTrue(new File(db.getWorkTree(), "b").exists());
               checkFile(new File(db.getWorkTree(), "a"),
                               "first line\nsec. line\nthird line\nfourth line\n");
               Iterator<RevCommit> history = git.log().call().iterator();
               assertEquals("Revert \"fixed a\"", history.next().getShortMessage());
               assertEquals("fixed b", history.next().getFullMessage());
               assertEquals("fixed a", history.next().getFullMessage());
               assertEquals("enlarged a", history.next().getFullMessage());
               assertEquals("create b", history.next().getFullMessage());
               assertEquals("create a", history.next().getFullMessage());
               assertFalse(history.hasNext());
       }
}
```

Comment: I guess that confirms it's simply not possible yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

- install latest nightly of EGit (0.11.xx)
- open History View
- right-click on the commit you want to revert in the currently checked out branch
- click "Revert Commit"

--
Matthias

Comment: I did that, but then I wasn't able to commit and push to the remote repository. I want a specific older commit to become HEAD...

Comment: @Lennon so you need a reset

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to low reputation, but I wanted to add the final piece to @Matthias Sohn's answer just in case anyone, like me, finds this via searching for how to do this.  His steps are here below so you don't have to scroll:

- install latest nightly of EGit (0.11.xx)
- open History View
- right-click on the commit you want to revert in the currently checked out branch
- click "Revert Commit"

This will add an entry at the top of the history view "Revert [previous commit comment]".  If you right click this new entry you will see an option to commit the Revert operation.  You need to do it from the History view because as @Lennon said, you cannot commit and push from the Package Explorer.

The downside to this method is it will Revert all changes in the Commit.  I would prefer to be able to rollback only a specific file that was in a Changeset, so if anyone knows of a way to do this please add on.

Answer (score 0):

Right click file which you want to revert -> Replace With -> HEAD revision